# result-dependent for-loop optimization in R?

Tags: r

I'm aware of of vectorization and how it can be applied to speed up for loops in R, but I cannot figure out a way to speed up code using vectors where each iteration is dependent on results from a previous iteration, or is dependent on an iterative random interval calculation.

For example:

Josh-- sorry about that.  So, here's more detail:

```
m <- c(1, 1)
w.r <- c(0.33592935393, 0.63825353030, 0.15335253356 )
```

and rlistl is a list of 3 2x2 matrices.  so, for the sake of conversation,

```
r0 <- matrix(0, 2, 2) 
r1 <- matrix(1, 2, 2)
r2 <- matrix(2, 2, 2)
rlist <- list(r0, r1, r2)

N <- 500
E <- matrix(0, N, 2)

for(i in 1:N) {
    r <- c(c(1:3) %*% rmultinom(1, 1, w.r))
    E[i, ] <- mvrnorm(1, m, rlist[[r]])
}
```

I've tried taking the "r <- multinom()" calcuation outside the loop, and rprof shows the majority of the time spent, obviously, is in mvnorm.  Can anybody figure out a way in R to speed this up using vectors?

Here's another example

```
for(i in 1:N) {
    if(d$V[i, 1] & d$V[i, 2]) QQ <- 1
    else if(! d$V[i, 1] & d$V[i, 2]) QQ <- 2
    else if(! d$V[i, 1] & ! d$V[i, 2]) QQ <- 3
    else if(d$V[i, 1] & ! d$V[i, 2]) QQ <- 4

    U[i, ] <- r1bvtruncnorm(mux=mu.U[i, ]/sd.r[r1], rho=rho, q=QQ)
```

}

Can't figure out a way to make that run any faster.  Part of my problem is that I'm a C/C++ programmer, but I've been trying to read up on R and want to make sure I'm not missing something easy.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Justin:

OK-- so I tried your suggestion, but as I feared, rep() doesn't behave like I was hoping.  I need a separate, random number each time, but using rep() just calls rmultinom once and replicates the result 100 times.

```
>rep(c(c(1:3) %*% rmultinom(1, 1, ww.r)), 100)
  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [38] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [75] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

> rep(c(c(1:3) %*% rmultinom(1, 1, ww.r)), 100)
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [38] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [75] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: What is `w.r` in the first code block? As it stands, neither example is reproducible, and you'll probably get better responses if you supply code that runs on our boxes too!

Comment: Josh-- sorry about that.  So, here's more detail:

m <- c(1, 1)
w.r <- c(0.252201578098282, 0.585225059235736, 0.162573362665982 )

and rlistl is a list of 3 2x2 matrices.  so, for the sake of conversation,

r0 <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
r1 <- matrix(1, 2, 2)
r2 <- matrix(2, 2, 2)
rlist <- list(r0, r1, r2)

Answer (score 0):

See Josh's comment for anything that I didn't guess right.

But assuming you didn't leave anything else out, `w.r` is constant and should be removed from the loop.  `m` is also constant.  'r' and rlist[[r]] are randomly generated but with constant parameters.  So what you're doing is generating a distribution `N` times from the same parameters, correct? If that's the case, there are many better choices than a for loop. e.g.

```
E <- matrix(rep(mvrnorm(1, 
                       m, 
                       rlist[[c(1:3 %*% rmultinom(1, 1, w.r))]]), 
                N),  
            N, 
            2)
```

which should give you the same result as your first for loop.

Your second example can just become a function and use `apply`.  However, without knowing the actual structure of the `d` object, its hard to know how best to approach it.  I'm assuming its something like a data.frame of data.frames or a named list of lists. Where `d$V` is some two dimensional data structure:

```
my.fun <- function(vec) {
    if(vec[1] & vec[2]) return(1)
    else if(! vec[1] & vec[2]) return(2)
    else if(! vec[1] & ! vec[2]) return(3)
    else if(vec[1] & ! vec[2]) return(4)
}

QQ <- apply(d$V, 1, my.fun)
```

Edited per comments:

```
r  <- 1:3 %*% rmultinom(N, 1, w.r)
E <- t(sapply(r, function(x) mvrnorm(1, m, rlist[[x]])))
```

Or on a single messy line:

```
t(sapply(1:3 %*% rmultinom(N, 1, w.r), function(x) mvrnorm(1, m, rlist[[x]])))
```

Comment: Yes-- so, w.r and m are both constant.  I didn't know you could use rep in that manner actually.  That's awesome!  I will try it.

Comment: Justin-- your suggestion did not work.  Please see the edit in my original post.

Comment: `rmultinom(N, 1, w.r)` fix it?

Comment: Yep-- that fixes the main issue but doesn't solve how to place that inside the rep() statement you originally posted, as there is no way that I can figure out to have rep iterate through those indices.